# How Do I can Generate a CDF Plot from Below PDF code and also it Histogram Plot?

Tags: distributions, histograms, cdf-format

I have tried many times to plot a CDF from the following PDF code , But I failed to get that however I have used the command CumulantGeneratingfunction[, ] but it coudn't work , any Help ?and also the same with Histogram plot ?

```
 f[z_?NumericQ, \[Mu]_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[Sqrt[6]/Sqrt[2*Pi]Exp[-(z - \[Mu])^2/(Pi)
]* Erf[(z - \[Mu])/(\[Sigma] Sqrt[2*Pi])]* Erfi[(z - \[Mu])/(\[Sigma] Sqrt[2*Pi])], {\[Sigma], 1, \[Infinity]}]
pdfF[\[Mu]_?NumericQ] := PDF[ProbabilityDistribution[f[x, \[Mu]], {x, - \[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]]
With[{n = 5},
  Show[
      Plot[
        Labeled[pdfF[#1][z], Row[{"\[Mu] = ", Rationalize[#1]}], Above], {z, -5, 5},
     PlotRange -> All,
        PlotStyle -> #2] &
    @@@
      Rest[{#, Hue[#]} & /@ Subdivide[0., 1., n]],
  ImageSize -> Large]]
With[{n = 5}, NIntegrate[pdfF[#][z], {z, -5, 5}] & /@ (Range[n]/n)]
```

Comment: First, the integral of `f` is not 1, so it is not a properly defined PDF function (e.g. `NIntegrate[f[z, 3], {z, -∞, ∞}]` returns 1.01826); you need to introduce a normalization factor. Furthermore, your use of `PDF[ProbabilityDistribution[f[x, μ], {x, -∞, ∞}]]` is redundant: `ProbabilityDistribution` will generate a distribution *assuming that its first argument is a well-defined PDF, normalized to* 1. When you apply `PDF` to that, you just get `f[x, μ]` back (evaluate `pdfF[2]`), so using `PDF[ProbabilityDistribution[f[...], ...]]` is completely equivalent to using your own `f`.

Comment: I have a normalization to 0.98 is that accepted PDF ?

Comment: Close, but not quite. A probability density function's integral over the entire space should be guaranteed to be exactly equal to 1.

Comment: I have adjusted it now I have got 0.99

Comment: @MarcoB , Pleas could u give me an answer below how i can plot CDF  , I have normalized it to 1 , But am stiil unable to plot generating CDF from That PDF